# .mp3 works .aac does not for merging picture + audio in batch

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

This works when its .mp3 however it doesnt work if the audio file type is aac, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
echo off
for %%a in ("*.aac") do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -an -vcodec copy "images\%%~na.jpg"
  "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -loop 1 -i  "images\%%~na.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest "video\%%~na.mp4" )
pause
```

Comment: Looks like you need to also run `for %%a in ("*.aac")` and then the rest for `.acc` files.

Comment: Ah sorry I edited the script, the issues happens with it as *aac it does work for mp3 format though

Answer (score 1):

Was running it in CMD, forgot windows cmd = % and batch = %%